Run Model trained on GPU in normal CPU : throws Error : No CUDA gpus are available / Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
I made models using Detecto which ultimately relied on GPUs for training and testing [hard lifting was done with Colab]. I now have to test these models on my laptop, which has a standard Intel Core i3 CPU, and I'm getting errors.
RUNTIME ERROR : No CUDA gpus are available  ( When I installed pytorch for CUDA)
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
installed pytorch for cpu gives error : Asssertion Error : Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
I need to run my model [deals with images] on my normal cpu instead of gpu
I already tried : torch.device('cpu') but this also seems not to help.
I want to run the ai model originally trained on GPU and realies on pytorch for it processing which trained on GPU in my CPU machine.

You installed the CPU only version of pytorch. The error is because somewhere in your code something is trying to use a GPU device. If you look at the stack trace, you should be able to find where.

@Karl My models are trained using Detecto, which uses GPU underneith for training, but is it possible to run the same model over a CPU?
By the way, I installed the GPU version of pytorch but it didn't address my issue. throws the error "RUNTIME ERROR: No CUDA gpus are available.". which is obvious, I don't have the required GPU.

It sounds like the library you are using assumes a GPU will be present. To run on CPU, you need to find the parts of the library that explicitly try to put data on the GPU and change it. Running the model on CPU is totally possible, but could be a pain depending on how the library is designed

I will try to use this approach
